# Script cannot fetch data from a web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to write a program in Python that can take the name of a stock and its price and print it. However, when I run it, nothing is printed. it seems like the data is having a problem being fetched from the website. I double checked that the path from the web page is correct, but for some reason the text does not want to show up.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/UKX:IND?in_source=topQuotes')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="priceText__1853e8a5"]/text()')
print ('Prices:' , Prices)
```

[here is the website I am trying to get the data from](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/UKX:IND?in_source=topQuotes)

I have tried BeautifulSoup, but it has the same problem.

Comment: Hey Adam, it is likely that the website has dynamic html, in which case you'll have to use `selenium`.

Comment: check what `page` returns but it looks like @JuanC is correct, `requests` returns a response from the server asking you to check a box to confirm you are not a robot

Comment: Bloomberg doesn't want you to scrape the site, since they want to force people to use their [api](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/). As already stated, you can use browser automation like Selenium to access the site elements via browser rather than web requests

Comment: If you know how to use Chrome inspect tools, you can directly target the AJAX api with cloned headers from your browser.

Comment: Yeah I was reading up on selenuium. I will keep it bookmarked for myself if I ever need it in the future.  thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the string `page.content`, you'll see that the website code it captures is actually for a captcha test, not the "real" destination page itself you see when you manually visit the website.  It seems that the website was smart enough to see that your request to this URL was from a script and not manually from a human, and it effectively prevented your script from scraping any real content.  So `Prices` is empty because there simply isn't a span tag of class `"priceText__1853e8a5"` on this special Captcha page.  I get the same when I try scraping with `urllib2`.

As others have suggested, Selenium (actual web automation) might be able to launch the page and get you what you need. The ID looks dynamically generated, though I do get the same one when I manually look at the page.  Another alternative is to simply find a different site that can give you the quote you need without blocking your script.  I tried it with https://tradingeconomics.com/ukx:ind and that works.  Though of course you'll need a different xpath to find the cell you need.

Comment: Yeah I was just reading up on selenium. Thankfully, It is working on another website I just tried with similar data, but only on the names since the prices are constantly being updated. I do not necessarily need to scrape prices from this particular site. I was just testing it on this site because it was the first one that popped up.

I am using this program for a website that displays financial data, but it is only updated once a day. I am going to assume that the program I am making will work with this website.